# Why does this assignment of a button object to a 2D array of buttons not work?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, button, basic

I am kind of new to programming in general, especially in Visual Basic. As part of a random project I am doing, I have declared a 2D array of type *button* and have then populated the array with buttons. I am trying to assign a new button to one of the buttons in the array and then access its `.text` property, but I get a null reference error. Instead of assigning one of the buttons in the array to a new button, I have also just tried to access the `.text` property of the button in the array, but I get the same error. Sorry if this is worded badly. I am still learning all the proper language.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim buttonarray(,) As Button = {{btn11, btn12}, {btn21, btn22}}
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim newbutton As Button

        newbutton = buttonarray(1, 1)
        lblOut.Text = newbutton.Text
        lblOut.Text = buttonarray(1, 1).Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is an example of what I'm trying to do. The buttons in the array are on *form1* and are declared in the designer file.

Comment: Can you add Tags for the environment you are using, is that `.net` `vb.net` with a `winforms` UI or something else?

Comment: Yes this is a Windows Form Application and it’s vb.net. Sorry i didn’t specify that in the post.